# What would natives take for "Today is so yesterday"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I saw this sentence "***Today is so yesterday***" on a T-shirt one of my American friends wore.

My first impression is that the sentence means what's happening today is just repeating what's happening in the past. But I feel there might be some other interpretations too.

What will be English natives' take for the sentence?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

"xxx is so yesterday" doesn't mean that xxx is the same as yesterday-in fact, the phrase isn't usually applied to dates at all. What it typically means is that xxx, whatever that may be, is out of fashion. It is a thing of yesterday, not a thing of today. There are several variants of this phrase in English, substituting in various past times, such as "xxx is so last year".

The t-shirt in question is (probably) a joke on the pace of changing fashions.

Comment: Are they joking that the pace of changing fashions is too slow?

Comment: @dan No too fast. I think the thought behind it is that you can barelly start adopting the fashion before it is already old. The pace is too fast to keep up.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - Yeah, it reminds me of an old TV ad: someone is driving home with a brand-new phone when he sees a new billboard announcing the arrival of the next version or generation of the phone.

Comment: To add to this good answer: Usually, you use this construction with things that have been gone for long. *Dude, listening to the disco music is so 70s.* / *Using dumbphones is so 2005!*. Naturally, the notion gets more ridiculous the shorter the distance between the date and now is.

Comment: By the same interpretation, it could also be taken to mean that today itself is out of fashion, i.e. life, in its current state, sucks.

Comment: I think its entirely plausible that the T-shirt is simply a *joke about the phrase* "(blank) is so yesterday", or perhaps a joke about *how often people use this phrase to declare things out of date*, by inserting something absurd. Plenty of ways to interpret it, I don't think there is any one right answer.

Comment: Or it may simply mean "I'm bored with today already."

Comment: Or "today was just like yesterday, even with all the changes made."

Comment: I think @dan's interpretation is far more likely than Mixxiphoid's. Most important though is that it is a joke and not to be taken literally or seriously ... so BradC's take is spot on.